# SAX time series representation in R using the jmotif package

Tags: r, time-series, sax

I am trying to represent a number of time series plots using SAX so that I can mine them for similarities. I am using the jmotif package in R:

```
#Create an example dataframe
example1 <- data.frame(flow=c(1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6),
                   weight1=c(7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6), 
                   weight2=c(8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6)) 
# Create a timeseries object
examplets1 <- ts(example1, start = 1, end = 6)

#Analysis
library(jmotif)
#Normalise the data using Znorm
examplezn <- znorm(examplets1, threshold = 0.01)
#Perform piecewise aggregate approximation
examplepaa <- paa(examplezn, 3)
#Represent time series as SAX
sax_via_window(examplepaa, 3, 3, 10, "mindist", 0.1)

#This produces the result
> sax_via_window(examplepaa, 3, 3, 10, "mindist", 0.1)
$`0`
[1] "bgh"
```

I am having trouble interpreting these results. What I would expect is a symbolic representation that I could associate with each column eg.  Flow: acc, weight1: bgh and so on. The real datset would have about 100 columns of ts data!

Am I incorrectly applying the method?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that I didn't "vectorize" jmotif, so its functions only applicable to an ordered sequence of numbers which represents the input timeseries, i.e., not to data frame objects or timeseries objects. Arguable, but I just wanted to keep it simple.

I did modify your code a bit to perform the task, hope it helps:

```
library(jmotif)

# create an example dataframe, list works the best cause library is not "vectorized"
example1 <- list(flow = c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9),
             weight1 = c(7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9),
             weight2 = c(8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9))

# this library makes working with not-vectorized code easier
library(plyr)

# z-normalize
examplezn <- llply(example1, function(x){znorm(x, threshold = 0.01)})

# perform piecewise aggregate approximation, probably not needed for following up with SAX transform, so just for illustration ...
llply(examplezn, function(x){paa(x, 3)})

# represent time series as SAX strings using via window SAX transform
example_sax <- llply(example1, function(x){sax_via_window(x, 3, 2, 3, "none", 0.1)})

# convert the result to a data frame, by rows though
df_by_row <- ldply(example_sax, unlist)

# and finally obtain a column-oriented data frame
df_by_column <- as.data.frame(t(df_by_row))
```